# Eclipse PHP Zend: "workspace in use" when i try to set my workspace in Apache2/htdocs?

Tags: php, eclipse, zend-framework, zend-studio, eclipse-pdt

i am trying to use my workspace `C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs`, as i need to in order to use my Zend Server, but i get the error `"workspace in use`"

i have:

- deleted all other copies of eclipse that i used
- looked for a `.metadata` folder but not found one in my current eclipse folder (brand new eclipse PDT with Zend)

any idea as to what the problem can be? and how to fix it :D

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your workspace directory for :

- .metadata and delete it (can be
  hidden in your explorer)
- .version.ini    , open it an delete
  all entrys

Answer (score 2):

I think deleting .metadata will cause you to lose your tracked projects. Im not positive though ( don't really want to test it haha). However if you go in that folder (WORKSPACE/.metadata/) and delete the .lock file it should allow you to open the workspace. Hope this helps!

Comment: This should be marked as the correct question. There is no need to delete the entire .metadata folder

Answer (score 1):

Just offering two other solutions for anyone who faces the workspace issue and ends up on this page.
[This is one solution](http://www.satya-weblog.com/2008/08/eclipse-workspace-in-use-or-cannot-be.html)
and the other solution is if you were working on eclipse by connecting to a server via ssh.
In this case, the ssh might time out and your eclipse process would still be active on the server.
Solution is:
Type **ps -aef | grep eclip**
Find the process number of eclipse and type **kill -9 process number**